# How can I add label in Xcode 4.5.2 the label should appear after the user click a button

Tags: iphone, xcode, label

I am trying to write my first IPhone app

in Xcode 4.5.2 I could not add atext to the label

I am trying to do the program in next video

http://youtu.be/0uVxxdZ5umY

it always not work and the error is use of undeclared identifier 'label'

and this always appear after I write    `labe.text`

in the `.m file`

thank you in advance

Comment: You should share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an IBAction of your button. In the method create a new Instance of UILabel and add it to your view.

Im not sure about the syntax.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
label.text = @"your text";
[self.view addSubview:label]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way is

```
UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20];
[yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]]; 
[yourSuperView addSubview:yourLabel];
```

And if you want to hide till user press the Button. You can do

```
[yourLabel setHidden:YES];
```